Defining $a$ in the axiom $a+0=a$
So my question is almost in the title.. In the Peano axiom for addition $a+0=a$ I don't find any clear definition of that what is $a$ weather on google, wikipedia or youtube.
Is it the set of all the positive integer? In this case there is something that will be missing because not only the positive integers are equal to themself when added to zero. But the problem is that the whole numbers are not yet defined before we define the addition in the Peano axiomatic.
So is there some more axiom added for the case where $a$ is not a positive integer?
Most deeply I'm interested on how to define mathematicaly an object that represent all the possible numbers.
Thank you for reading.
Ps: please don't identify my question as an other. This website is really badly designed and it will close my subject weather I'm agree or not or even if the whole community agree or not. So please don't be a bick and just tell me in the comment if you think that my question was already answer not by using the website delation system that just favorise online mobbing.

I would say $a+0=a$ is part of the definition of addition rather than an axiom, though this is not particularly important.  Here $a$ is any "natural number".  To get the natural numbers to correspond to the non-negative integers, you need an additional identification: $S(0)=1$.

Should it be $a+0=a$ in the title?

@Martin: Yes. I edited.

@Henry. According go wikipedia $a+0=0$ is one the two axioms that define the addition function. If I understood well.

@Yves Daoust. No

I don't know an other but suggestions are welcome.

Peano axioms define what the "system" of natural numbers is stating a set of basic properties.
Thus, the system of natural numbers is every collection of mathematical objects satisfying the axioms.
The first axiom states that there is a "special" object that we call zero: $0$.
The axiom for sum: $+$, states that: for every object $a$ of the system, $a+0=a$.
Having defined the naturals, we can go on with the construction of other "number systems", like that of the integer. Having done this, we specify that the non-negative integers behave exactly as the naturals do.
See Edmund Landau, Foundations of Analysis (1929), page 1:

We assume the following to be given: A set of objects called natural numbers, possessing the properties - called axioms - to be listed below.

Note: Landau's book is quite terse, but you can supplement it with e.g. Terence Tao's Anlysis I: Chapter 2 Starting at the beginning: the natural numbers.
For all number systems, see e.g. Ethan Bloch, The Real Numbers and Real Analysis (2011).

So if I understand well your answer, $a$ is just an "object" that satisfy the Peano axioms. But, at this point the only objects that are satisfying the Peano axioms before the definition of addition are positive integer only. So based on this my confusion remain the same.

@lazare - if we follow the axiomatic approach, we have objects and we do not know if they are naturals, integers, reals before stating the relevant axioms. In "real life", we know the counting numbers that we learned at school and we verify that Peano axioms capture basic properties of counting numbers and we verify that they (the axioms) are enough to prove ALL known properties of numbers: associativity, commutativity, etc.

So, can you explain me for example how can I prove that $-1+0=0$ , $\frac{1}{2}+0=0$ and $i+0=0$ just based on the Peano axioms ?

@lazare - Peano axioms are about NATURALS: in natural numbers system there is no $-1$. For Integers you have to add new axioms.

See here for integers. Also here

Ok so $a$ is only a natural number. And for explaining the behave of non natural numbers added to zero we need new axioms. Thank you for your answer.
